# Torque requirement for the motor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque

I have a load of almost 15 kg. 
Both the pulley diameter = 0.6m 
Distance between the center of both the pulley is 0.8m.

Loads are permanently attached to the belt.[image]

i will use a HTD belt for this system.

Can anyone help me find the torque required for the motor?
Thinking of using a stepper or servo motor to rotate it in steps of 10cm.

i dont have any knowledge about the frictional losses

Comment: The friction is everything for this problem.  The load balances itself out since it's on a closed loop.  The only things you need to consider are the friction and the desired acceleration.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold so you [edit] in additional details surrounding your question.  As pointed out in a comment and answer, there are a number of parameters you need to specify before this would be answerable.

Comment: I don't know that it's unanswerable - see my answer below. That said, I think my answer leaves a lot more work for OP to do, which hopefully will get him/her to ask the question, "So how DO I calculate load inertia" or, "So what IS a normal force" or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\tau_{\mbox{required}} = \mbox{acceleration torque} + \mbox{friction losses} + \mbox{slope/hill climbing opposing force} \\
\tau_{\mbox{required}} = I\alpha + \mu F_{\mbox{normal}} r_{\mbox{effective}} + mg \sin{\theta} r_{\mbox{effective}} \\
$$

where:

- $\tau_{\mbox{required}}$ is the required torque
- $I$ is the load inertia
- $\alpha$ is the desired peak acceleration
- $\mu$ is the cumulative coefficient of friction covering all friction losses in the drivetrain
- $F_{\mbox{normal}}$ is the normal force between the vehicle and the ground
- $r_{\mbox{effective}}$ is the effective hub radius
- $m$ is the mass of the vehicle
- $g$ is the gravitational constant
- $\theta$ is the slope of the ground you are on

When you can define all of the above terms, plug them in and you have an answer for your required torque. No need to update your question.

Comment: Assuming this is a design for a caterpillar-track for a vehicle, I don't think the friction between track and ground is relevant for the torque calculation.  Instead, I think the internal friction of the track components is more important (pulleys, belts, etc.).  I would replace the second term of your equation with just a generic "friction force" multiplied by hub radius.

Comment: I agree; I updated the answer.

Comment: T= 1/2 *D (F + uWg)  where  T= torque  , D= roller Diameter in m, W = mass of load in kg , g =gravity acc , u = frictional coefficient , F =external force.. Does this formula make sense ? if yes what will be external force for this system , D= 0.2m , W = 15 kg , u =0.8 , F= ??